# Why I cannot assign event listener to a button?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, event-listener

Here's the code to add event listeners to all the button elements in my html. In result – no registered event listeners and no errors as well.

```
window.onload = function(){
    addEvListeners();
    // This function is to assign ELs to buttons in my HTML
    function addEvListeners(){
        var target = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
        for (i = 0; i <= target.length - 1; i ++){
            target[i].addEventListener("click", function(){model();},false);
        }
    }
    function model(){
        return true; // just for placeholder
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? The function called just returns true. Nothing is logged. BTW `i <= target.length - 1` can be replaced with `i < target.length`. And `i = 0; i < target.length` should be replaced with `i = 0, j=target.length; i < j` (caching length)

Comment: Not sure what is 'not working', but one thing i see is that  you should remove the space between `i ++` in your for loop.

Comment: And how do you know, all it does is return `true` ?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine here -> https://jsfiddle.net/4jzgcktz/

Comment: My guess is the buttons are not there.

Comment: Works fine for me too https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/cfckvvzw/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
                addEvListeners();
                // This function is to assign ELs to buttons in my HTML
                function addEvListeners(){
                    var target = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
                    for (i = 0; i <= target.length - 1; i ++){
                        target[i].addEventListener("click", function(){model();},false);
                    }
                }
                function model(){
                    console.log('yo!');
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>Click Me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

This worked for me. I ended up getting a yo in my console. Is it possible that your button element doesn't exist at `onload`?